# Convert php String to int array and sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this string in php.

```
$string = "17,3,25,29,35,81,40,45,50";
```

I need to explode it to an integer array and sort it in ascending order.

I used this code but that is not working.

```
$myArray = array_map('intval', explode(',', $string));
$sortedArray = sort($myArray);
print_r($sortedArray);
```

What is the error?

Comment: How is this code not working?

Comment: Could you please define "not working"?

Comment: It gives me the output as 1. I expected to print the sorted array.

Comment: check my asnwer below it works

Comment: @Asankasanjaya `sort` returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. It does not return the sorted array. The array variable is mutated. ([Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 

$string = "17,3,25,29,35,81,40,45,50";
$myArray = explode(',', $string);
sort($myArray);
print_r($myArray);// to print array

echo $newstring =implode(',',$myArray);
```

Comment: Marked as the answer:)

Answer (score 4):

`sort` function doesn't return a sorted array, it sorts an argument array by reference. What you need to do is:

```
$myArray = array_map('intval', explode(',', $string));
sort($myArray);
print_r($myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "17,3,25,29,35,81,40,45,50";
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $string)));
asort($array);
$array = implode(', ', $array);
print_r($array);
```